# Convert block of code PineScript to thinkscript

Tags: if-statement, pine-script, thinkscript

I want to convert this line of code from pinescript to thinkscript ( Thinkorswim )
How can I write this? I'm having problems with multiple if statements

```
isAboveEma01 = line_01 > line_01[1] and line_01 > line_50 ? blue : line_01 > line_01[1] and line_01 < line_50 ? #cc00cc : line_01 < line_01[1] and line_01 > line_50 ? #0388FF : line_01 < line_01[1] and line_01 < line_50 ? #BD003A : na
```

I try this, but doesn't work:

```
line_01.AssignValueColor( 
if (line_01 >= line_01[1] and line_01 > line_50) then {
line_01.Color("PositiveUp") ;
} else if (line_01 >= line_01[1] and line_01 < line_50) then {
line_01.Color("PositiveDown");
} else if line_01 < line_01[1] and line_01 > line_50 then {
line_01.Color("NegativeUp");
}) else line_01.Color("NegativeDown");
);
```

Comment: Doesn't thinkscript have if-else statements?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of 'if' statement is in the official [tutorial](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Expressions,_Declarations_and_Statements#.E2.80.98if.E2.80.99_statement)
Simply note that PineScript is sensitive to indentation/whitespaces.